# C# Location Based Service application advices

Tags: c#, location-based-service

I am looking forward to get myself involved in C# programming, specifically in LBS apps.

If anyone could take a minute to help with some advices, it would be appreciated.

Kind of: the environment(tools,the best IDE);the technologies;  documents(video tutorial,books); the itinerary of the development(an overview of the structure of the app).

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for SO. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you have specific programming questions as you learn they will be welcome here

Comment: Also, I've formatted your question to not consist entirely of quotes (lines which started with `>`).

Comment: Thank you @AlexS . I`ll try to be more specific next time.